# Optimizing Real-Time Object Detection with YOLO V8 on Multiple IP Cameras via RTSP Protocol

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera, rtsp

### Context

I'm working on a DIY project involving object detection using the YOLO V8 model on six IP cameras accessed through the RTSP protocol. Currently, YOLO models don't support multiple video sources out of the box, and I am exploring solutions to this limitation.

### Problem Statement

My initial approach involves using a Redis server to queue frames from each camera sequentially. However, this method leads to a significant delay (approximately 5-6 seconds) to complete a detection cycle for all cameras, creating a backlog and hindering real-time detection. I am seeking advice on optimizing this process to achieve near real-time detection without sacrificing accuracy.

### Specific Questions

1. **Alternative Approaches:** Are there more efficient methods or architectures to handle multiple video streams for real-time object detection using YOLO V8?
2. **Image Dimensions:** How do the dimensions of the captured frames impact the speed and accuracy of detection? What are the optimal dimensions for balancing detection speed and accuracy?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to effectively approach this problem. Thank you for your time and expertise.

### Attempts and Constraints

- I have considered and attempted a queue-based approach using Redis, but it results in significant delays.
- Real-time or near real-time detection is a crucial requirement for this project.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]

Comment: I apologize for the errors in my post. Thanks a lot @ChristophRackwitz for the edits.

Comment: Why u are using redis you can just use internal queues. Resolution depense on your scene, you need a specif amount of Pixels to detect an object so if your cameras have wide scenes you need a better Resolution as when u have Tele sences. Less Resolution meens less computation. U could just use I-Frames for the analyis you dont need 25 FPS for object detection. You could Look into a Producer, consumer Pattern for fetching frames and the detection